# How can a PHP application tell if the loaded swf movie uses the clickTAG

Tags: php, flash, banner, clicktag, swf-decompiler

That and other information about the movie, like the width, height, duration, framerate and if it make other urlRequest.

I need this for a banner management system.

Comment: Do you mean flash remoting for php? Maybe you're looking for something like this [AMFPHP](http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe look into using the external interface and let the swf just tell your php app whats what.

The swf could call a javascript function in the page sending it a list of parameters you are interested in and pass it on to the php. This only really applies if the swf is not viral though.

If you have no control of where the swf is embedded you could just send a post request with name pair values (width, height etc) to a php page.

Also as timwebdev says AMFPHP would be a good solution for swf / backend communication.

If I had a better idea of your requirements I might be able to suggest a more relevant solution.